# Routes under Routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

i have a dashboard component with a sub component called SMS. Now, the SMS component also has it routing list. How can i route under the sms navigation bar under the dashboard component. Below is the screenshot

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0):

The angular official site has a working example in 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

You need to implement a "feature module" as described in the article. There are few concepts you need to be familiarised. It is hard to describe in here

Please go to hero module and the answer is there.

in app/hero/hero.component.3.ts

```
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  template: `
<h2>Heroes of {{userName}}</h2>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
providers: [ HeroService ]
})
export class HeroComponent {
  userName = '';
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
  this.userName = userService.userName;
  }
}
```

and in hero-routing.module.3.ts

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { Routes,
     RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HeroComponent }       from './hero.component.3';
import { HeroListComponent }   from './hero-list.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '',
component: HeroComponent,
children: [
  { path: '',    component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
    ]
  }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HeroRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {smsRoutes} from 'yourpath';
```

export const DashboardRoutes: Routes =[

```
  {
    path: 'dashboard',

    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [

        {path:'sms', component: SmsComponent},
        {path:'sms', children: SmsRoutes}


    ]

  }
];
```

your SmsRoutes should be

```
export const SmsRoutes: Routes =[
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'quicksms',pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path:'quicksms', component:quickSmsComponent}
    ];
```

This will work actually in dashboardRoutes you can  directly have one path with children and have that default '' to SmsComponent but I ran in to issues.You can try that even

Comment: yeah it runs to issues..my app doesn;t load

Comment: Did the above solution work for you? if not what's the error?

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid route configuration of route '{path: "", redirectTo: "quicksms"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Invalid route configuration of route '{path: "", redirectTo: "quicksms"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'.

Comment: i am able to route now from http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/sms to  http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/sms/quicksms when i click on the quicksms tab but the navigation bar disappears instead of keeping still